# JQuery Live Load Photo Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to create an image upload script in JQuery 1.9.1 where the image is previewed live in the browser. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});

<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
<input type='file' id="imgInp" />
```

I've tried running this code through JSFiddle and it works completely fine but on my website it only changes the file name but doesn't preview the image. Does anyone know why this may be?

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9TZ6/

Comment: What is the output `src` of `#blah` ?

Comment: What browser & version do you use?

Comment: @Murali It's Firefox 24.0, but I'm using the same browser for JS Fiddle and the script works fine

Comment: If it works fine on JSFiddle you might want to post the fiddle.